# from mysql to Yii syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

How to do that in Yii syntax?

```
(SELECT hist1.id_order, hist1.id_order_state, hist1.date_add
 FROM ps_order_history hist1
 INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT id_order, MAX(date_add) AS date_add
  FROM ps_order_history
  GROUP BY id_order) hist2
  ON hist1.id_order = hist2.id_order AND hist1.date_add = hist2.date_add) sel
```

I tried to relate the table ps_order_history with itself

```
public function relations() {
    "last_state" => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'OrderHistory', array('id_order' => 'id_order', 'date_add' => 'date_add'), 'group' => 'ls.id_order', 'select' => array('ls.id_order', 'MAX(date_add) AS ls.date_add'), 'alias'=>'ls'));
}
```

But I don't know how to make it right.

Comment: Your SQL statement is incomplete. Also, can you paste what you have tried in the Yii syntax so far?

Answer (score 0):

For very complex queries, I suggest you use the direct SQL command with the CDbCommand in Yii, as the active records may require a lot more of time and memory to execute.

Answer (score 0):

For anything beyound simple queries i use either direct SQL or preferably stored procedures.

The pain of trying to get any ORM framework do what i want beyond basic CRUD operations is too much for me too handle.